# python while loop implementation

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I have this piece of code below. What I want is to repeat the raw_input and repeat the if statement if the user prompt the wrong option

```
firewall = raw_input('Please, select IE13PVPNFW01 or IE23PVPNFW01 > ')
if firewall == 'IE13PVPNFW01':
  device = {'IE13PVPNFW01': {'ip': '10.248.40.93'}}
elif firewall == 'IE23PVPNFW01':
  device = {'IE23PVPNFW01': {'ip': '10.42.19.58'}}
else:
  print "Wrong device, options available IE13PVPNFW01 or IE23PVPNFW01"
```

Thanks

Comment: add a while loop, and break when ok...

Comment: I already new that. If I am asking is because I need help to implement that. Any example?

Comment: follow the link on the question I linked to. Of course you'll have to adapt to your needs. Basically I'd do a `while True:` and `break` when I define `device`

Comment: If I do that and device I put a different device name the loop run to infinite. Instead to redirect to other links (that like in this case are different on my question) would be easier and better if you give me an example using my code. In this way I can have a real understanding to how implement it

Comment: Never mind. I have managed to fix by my own

Comment: way to go. See, you can make it. I _never_ used a debugger for python code. Everything I debugged with `print` statements. Been doing that for 10 years now. Good luck.